# bracket in front

Tags: java

Below is the sample code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < clientListFromFile.size(); i++)
    {
        DisplayClient dc = null; // DisplayClient is another class
        dc = (DisplayClient)clientListFromFile.get(i); // clientListFromFile is the a list.
    }
```

can I know what is the means of putting a  `Displayclient` infront the `clientListFromFile` ?

```
int prevID = (int)clientList.get(clientListCount-1);
```

this is another example. why put the `(int) infront clientList.get(clientListCount-1)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a cast - you're telling Java that the variable is of a type that *might be* more specific than it knows about at compile time. With this comes a degree of danger, in that you have to check at runtime it's definitely of that type, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

This used to be used extensively, especially in collections, before the introduction of generics. However, generics provide a greater degree of defining types at compile time, so many casts are no longer needed. If you find you need casts when retrieving items from the list, you're probably not declaring the generic type properly (or at all), and should look into fixing this.

The following code uses the old syntax, without generics. Note how the last line doesn't compile, because the compiler doesn't know anything about the type of the list, so the type is always object. Hence, we need a cast to get it to work.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("hello");
String s = list.get(0); //Doesn't compile
String s = (String)list.get(0); //Does compile
```

This approach is discouraged now, and really is only still allowed for backwards compatibility reasons (it was the only way of doing things before generics were introduced.) We have to remember the type of the list, what was put in it and cast accordingly - and if something that's not a string makes its way into the list, nothing would stop it. The following example uses generics so does away with the cast:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("hello");
String s = list.get(0);
```

With this approach, everything we put into the list and get out of the list is guaranteed to be a string - anything else and the code won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

This is a cast and is not necessary if you use *generics* in your `List`declaration, for example

```
List<? extends Client>
```

Now your loop will look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clientListFromFile.size(); i++) {
   Client dc = = clientListFromFile.get(i); 
}
```

Comment: What if it's List<Client>?

Comment: I would say to look at your design and use common methods in your `Client` to allow polymorphism find the methods you want.

Answer (score 1):

this is call a cast. you can find more information about it [here](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting).

Answer (score 1):

It is an explicit cast. I'd imagine the list is more generic, so the code is explicitly casting to that particular type.

Implicit casting can be done in some cases (upcasting for example) but downcasting usually requires an explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

Probably both lists are not using a specific Type, and they are either rawtypes `List clientListFromFile = new ArrayList();` Or they are using `List<Object>`.

If that is the case, when you retrieve objects from the list `list.get(...)` you need to cast to the object which is in the list.

So basically its casting that described there